# How to count the number of checkboxes selected in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-for

I have a form_for method that asks what programming languages you know, and it looks like this :

```
<%=form_for(:user) do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
<%= f.check_box :html5 %> <%= f.label :html5, "Html 5" %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
<%= f.check_box :css3 %> <%= f.label :css3, "CSS 3" %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
<%= f.check_box :ruby %> <%= f.label :ruby %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
<%= f.check_box :python %> <%= f.label :python %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And I want to give the user a certain class based on how many checkboxes they select (the class being devise user classes with the [enum method](http://www.bicrement.com/articles/2014/multiple-models-in-devise.html))
I dont know where to start, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have columns named as `ruby`, `python` etc in the User table ?

Comment: Yeah, what should I do?

Comment: No, I just asked. The best way to design is using JSONB if on postgres. Or use serialize. But to answer your question, you need to use Jquery. Use some common class on the checkboxes. And then use Jquery to bind an `onClick` event on those. So on each click, you can then count how many checkboxes are checked by using some CSS selectors.

Comment: Are you wanting to count the checkboxes in the controller action? If so, what do the `params` look like when the form is submitted?

Comment: I have a params method in an if statement in the view that looks like :     <% if params[:html5] == 1 %>
    <% current_user.beginner! %>
    <% else %>
    <% end %> which tests for the html element